# Is there an easier way of writing several if/else statements into eachother?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I sometimes have myself writing code which requires several layers of if/else statements incorporated into each other (example can be found below).
I was wondering if I could shorten it up a bit, because sometimes I have trees of if/else statements of over 70 lines of code, and they are honestly just filling way too much compared to how many of the lines seem redundant.

Here's an example code:

```
if (labelGiveTip1.Visible == true)
{
    if (labelGiveTip2.Visible == true)
    {
        labelGiveTip3.Visible = true;
        if (labelGiveTip3.Visible == true)
        {
            Custom_DialogBox.Show("All of your hints for this assignment is used, do you want annother assignmment?", //main text argument
                "Error: No more hints",  //header argument
                "Back",                  //first button text argument
                "Get a new assignment"); //second button text argument
                                         //this is a custom dialog box

            result = Custom_DialogBox.result; 
            switch (result) 
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    buttonNextAssignment.PerformClick(); 
                    break;

                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    break; 

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        labelGiveTip2.Visible = true;
    }
}
else
{
    labelGiveTip1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: `labelGiveTip3.Visible = true; if (labelGiveTip3.Visible == true) { }` This condition quite seem to be unnecessary as it will always be true.

Comment: Personally, I hate code where boolean expressions have an extra comparison to true or false like `if (condition == true)` and `if (condition == false)`. I prefer `if (condition)` and `if (!condition)`.

Comment: I try to use the general rule that if a method spans over one full screen vertical then it needs to be refactored. So if you have 70 lines of code then you've gone too far.

Answer (score 3):

In my code I tend to check the false condition first and return ASAP. This approach has helped me over years to reduce deeply nested if else. Other than that try to separate related functionalities in to different methods. The example method provided crams too much of logic into one method. If you have ReSharper, it suggests nice improvements and over a period of time, it becomes a habit.

Answer (score 2):

You may check the negated variant of the condition and use `else if` conditions to avoid that much nesting. E.g. a simplified version for your code:

```
if (!labelGiveTip1.Visible)
    labelGiveTip1.Visible = true;
else if(!labelGiveTip2.Visible)
    labelGiveTip2.Visible = true;
else
{
    labelGiveTip3.Visible = true;
    Custom_DialogBox.Show("All of your hints for this assignment is used, do you want annother assignmment?", //main text argument
        "Error: No more hints",  //header argument
        "Back",                  //first button text argument
        "Get a new assignment"); //second button text argument
                                 //this is a custom dialog box



    result = Custom_DialogBox.result; 
    switch (result) 
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            {
                buttonNextAssignment.PerformClick(); 
                break;
            }
        case DialogResult.Cancel:
            {
                break; 
            }
        default:
            {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

It is also unnecessary to write `labelGiveTip1.Visible == true` or `labelGiveTip1.Visible == false` when they are already boolean values.